# Why returning (null) from MPMediaPicker (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am programming to get the iPhone music library to display, the user selects a song, then this song title is reflected in a `UILabel`. If only it was that simple! I have tried getting the `MPMediaItem` into a `NSString` then the `UILabel` reflecting this, but i'm just getting (null) returned!

```
- (IBAction)showMediaPicker:(id)sender {
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAny];

    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    //mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select Your Favourite Song!";

    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
}

- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItem *) mediaItemCollection {

    NSString *titleString = [mediaItemCollection valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@",titleString];


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to grab the title for a mediaItemCollection. You need to get the individual song title like this:

```
MPMediaItem *selectedSong = [mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *titleString = [selectedSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

Also by the way, you have the wrong delegate setup for your MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate:

It should be:

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
```

-You have the MPMediaItemCollection as just an MPMediaItem

Comment: +1 Thats been an amazing help, thank you! I noticed the wrong delegate setup shortly after writing the post. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept the answer if you're satisfied. Thanks!